# How to override BOLD on the toolbar in ckEditor

Tags: javascript, button, overriding, ckeditor

When ever i click on **B**  in ckEditor, i want to pop a msgbox like **alert('Good Morning')** .
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do like this, for example :

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['name_of_your_instance'],
button = editor.toolbox.toolbars[0].items[0].button,
f = button.click;
button.click = function(m) {
    alert('Good Morning');
    f(m);
};
```

Of course, you need to know the index of the toolbar, the index of the item, and the name of the instance ^^